# Is there a classification of homomorphisms $S_n \to S_{n+k}$ for small $k$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Homomorphisms $B_n \to B_{2n}$ and $B_n \to S_{2n}$ have been classified in [Chen–Kordek–Margalit - Homomorphisms between braid groups](https://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Edmargalit7/papers/bn2bn.pdf) and [Lin - Braids and permutations](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404528) respectively. I am interested in the corresponding question for symmetric groups:  what are the homomorphisms $S_n \to S_{n+k}$ (up to conjugation)?

I know from [Explicit description of all morphisms between symmetric groups.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36452/explicit-description-of-all-morphisms-between-symmetric-groups) that such a classification is difficult in full generality—I am willing to restrict my attention to suitably small $k$. The answer to the linked question discusses the classification of maximal subgroups of $S_m$ isomorphic to $S_n$, but I do not see how this is directly useful, as the image of a map $S_n \to S_{n+k}$ needn't be maximal.

When $k = 1$ and $n + 1 \neq 6$, the only index $n+1$ subgroups of $S_{n+1}$ are point stabilizers. Thus, any non-cyclic map $S_n \to S_{n+1}$ is conjugate to the obvious inclusion.

When $k > 1$, we may combine* the identity map $S_n \to S_n$ with a sign representation $S_n \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to S_{k}$ to produce a map $S_n \to S_{n+k}$ not conjugate to an inclusion. Following Chen–Kordek–Margalit, we might hope that these are all such homomorphisms (for small $k$).

Is anything known about these homomorphisms?

*In case it wasn't clear: this combination is found by letting $S_n$ act on $[1,\ldots, n]$ and $S_k$ act on $[n+1,\ldots,n+k]$

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302185/counting-symmetric-subgroups-of-symmetric-groups

Comment: Small comment: I think the exception for $k = 1$ is when $n+1=6$, not $n=6$.

Comment: What is a cyclic map $S_n \to S_{n + 1}$? \\ Your composition was originally $S_n \to \mathbb Z_2 \to S_k$, but, since you wanted the result to be a map $S_n \to S_{n + k}$, I figured the final target should be $S_{n + k}$, and edited accordingly.  I hope that this was all right.

Comment: @LSpice I am using Lin's terminology--a cyclic map is a map with cyclic image. Here, this just means "doesn't kill $A_n$". I have reverted your edit and elaborated on what I mean by "combine the identity map..."

Comment: Ah, I [see](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421138/is-there-a-classification-of-homomorphisms-s-n-to-s-nk-for-small-k#comment1081892_421138).  I apologise for my wrong edit.

Comment: The theory of representations of the symmetric groups is well developed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As spin observed in a comment below, if you know all (conjugacy classes of) subgroups of $S_n$ of index up to $m$, then you can determine the equivalence classes of homomorphisms $\phi:S_n \to S_m$, because the subgroups tell you the possible actions on the orbits of the image of $\phi$. The subgroups of index up to $m=n^2$ are listed explicitly in Mikko Korhonen's answer to the the MSE post [Large subgroups of Symmetric Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536888).

As an illustration, I will answer the question on the assumption that $k<n$.

For $n \ge 5$, a homomorphism from $S_n$ that is not injective has image of order $1$ or $2$, so we can restrict attention to injective maps $\phi:S_n \to S_{n+k}$.

From the MSE post referred to above we find that, for $n>6$, the only subgroups of index less than $2n$ are $S_n$, $A_n$, and the point stabilizers, which are isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$.

So if $S_n$ is acting faithfully on the set $\Omega := \{1,2,\dotsc,n+k\}$ with $k<n$, then there must be a single orbit $\Delta$ of length $n$ on which $S_n$ acts faithfully.

Since we are interested in classifying maps up to conjugation, we can assume that $\Delta = \{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ and that the image of $\phi(g)$ restricted to $\Delta$ is $g$ for all $g \in S_n$.

Furthermore, the image of $\phi$ restricted to $\Omega \setminus \Delta$ has order $1$ or $2$.

So, $\phi(g)_{\Omega \setminus \Delta} = 1$ for $g \in A_n$, and for $g \in S_n \setminus A_n$, we have, up to conjugation,
$\phi(g)_{\Omega \setminus \Delta}$ can be
$1$, or $(n+1,n+2)$, or $(n+1,n+2)(n+3,n+4)$, etc., which gives a total of $\lfloor \frac{k+2}{2} \rfloor$ equivalence classes of injective homomorphisms $\phi$.

Comment: Does the subscript in $\phi(g)_{\Omega \setminus \Delta}$ indicate restriction?

Comment: Yes that's right, the restriction of $\phi(g)$ to $\Omega \setminus \Delta$.

Comment: I guess the basic principle is that if you know all transitive actions of $S_n$ on $\leq k+n$ points, then you know all homomorphisms $S_n \rightarrow S_{n+k}$. Each homomorphism corresponds to a partition $\{1,\ldots,n+k\} = X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_t$ where $X_i$ is a transitive $S_n$-set. Then two homomorphisms are equivalent if and only if up to isomorphism of $G$-sets, then the set of $X_i$ that occur and the number of times they occur are the same.

Comment: And finding all transitive actions of $S_n$ on $\leq k+n$ points up to isomorphism of $G$-sets amounts to finding subgroups $H < S_n$ with $[S_n : H] \leq k+n$ up to conjugacy. For $k = n^2-n$ the list is in the link MSE answer, I guess $k = n^2$ will not need much more work.

Comment: @spin Yes that's right - I've edited my answer to clarify that point.